# ffmpeg- is there any limitation on number of drawtext filter used in a single command?

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

i have to write different text on a number of images. The final filter command is quite large (> 500 draw text filters in a single command). I am writing this to a text file and using filter_complex_script to read it.
If the number of frames and filter is small, it is working fine, but for a configuration with large number of images and draw text filters, it fails. Error is:

```
Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'enable=between(n,180,180):fontsize=28:fontfile=C\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:fontcolor=0x000000:text=109.0:x=581:y=527-th'
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory
```

Comment: I know this is a couple years old, but are you able to share the command causing the error?

Comment: @ZevAverbach Bit late to the show but recently ran into something very similar. 

.\ffmpeg.exe -y -r 29.97 -i "c:/video.mpg" -filter_complex_script "c:\myscript.txt" -r 29.97 -q:v 1 "c:\output.mpg"  

Seems to be related to these tickets:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5983#no1
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6281

Appears to be no resolution